# How to replace all attachment links in post with media file link

Tags: wordpress

I've been breaking my head over this for a few days but I yet have to find a proper solution. I'm working on a Wordpress site, where all images inside posts are linking to the corresponding attachment pages. I want to use a lightbox but obviously this would require changing all the links back to the media files directly (e.g. xyz.jpg).

The site has a significant number of posts and images so it would be impossible to do this manually.

Does anyone know of a plugin or other solution that would simply replace - in bulk - all of the image links to link to the media file, instead of the attachment page?

Comment: when you attach any image from back end than `Link To` Option set for attachment link.

Comment: I know, but I need an automatic way to change them after they have already been placed.

Comment: See:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004026/how-to-fetch-all-images-from-particular-page-id-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one answer that, although jQuery-based, did the trick, and is much quicker than and safer than a PHP-script to go through the whole DB. The drawback is that it will link to the resized image url instead of the full image url. There's probably a way to catch that with jQuery as well, but this was enough for my needs.

```
$("article.my-post-class a img").each( function(){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).parent("a").attr("href", src);
});
```